# How to avoid broken pipe error

Tags: python, sockets

I am using Python sockets to connect 50+ clients to a server to transfer images. I am using a wireless network to connect them. One issue I've come across is that when there is no communication for a while say 10 minutes, the software breaks. Otherwise it works fine.

Here's the send method on the client side:

```
f = open(fullpath, "rb")
filesize = str(os.path.getsize(fullpath))
s.send(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
while True:
    data = f.read(512)
    if not data:
        break
    s.send(data)
f.close() 
print("Finished sending image to server")
output("Finished sending image to server")
```

And here is the receive method on the server side:

```
client[0].send(str.encode("start"))
data = client[0].recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
filesize = int(data)
f = open(filenames[count], "wb")
currentSize = 0
while currentSize < filesize:
    data = client[0].recv(512)
    if not data:
       break
    if len(data) + currentSize > filesize:
       data = data[:filesize-currentSize]
    f.write(data)
    currentSize += len(data)
f.close()
```

On the client side I get the error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe. On the server side I get the error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte.
The error happens when the client is sending the filesize.

Is there an error in my code? Could I have the server and clients constantly send back and forth strings to keep the connection alive?

Comment: Can't say exactly why the server is choking on the data, but maybe you'll find that using `struct.pack()` and `struct.unpack()` to transmit your file size will be more reliable.

Comment: If you use TCP, you should know that is a *stream* protocol. Packets my be reassembled by any network equipment, so `data = client[0].recv(1024).decode('utf-8')` is likely to eat more data than the size. Anyway, you should post the full error message with the stacktrace and say on what line it occurs.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I lowered the bytes in the recv method and I haven't seen the error yet. I'll keep testing and I'll post the stacktrace if it happens again.